# Missing Unity launcher and top panel in 14.04, using Nvidia, with slightly stretched graphics

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics, 14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu, so apologies for not knowing the correct lingo for everything. I just upgraded to 14.04 on my Macbook Pro 5,5 (mid-2009). 13.04 worked great, but I'm having some issues with 14.04. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! I've combed through a lot of discussion threads on this forum and others that address this, trying various fixes, all to no avail.

1) I'm missing the unity bar and top menu bar (where it shows wifi, time, calendar, etc etc). Ctrl-Alt-T doesn't get me terminal. Installed Unity Tweak Tool, reset unity, nothing is working. The top panel appears at the login screen, but disappears right after I enter my password and log in.
(I am able to open things via TTY and command line).

2) The appearance of...everything...seems wonky. It's like the aspect ratio is off - the image appears skinnier and taller than the screen -- for example, when I move my mouse to the bottom of the screen, the screen shifts, like I'm pushing the edge of the screen down, and the image (wallpaper, window, whatever I have open) moves up. Like the image doesn't fit the screen somehow.

I have a feeling that this is a graphics thing, and have updated and am using an nvidia driver (331 version). I have tinkered with the appearance setting, which didn't help.

Thank you in advance for any help, advice, potential tweaks, etc!

Answer (score 0):

To get the unity bar, you must download CompizConfig Settings Manager from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Once you're in Compiz...  Scroll Down until you get to the "Desktop" tab.
From there, click on the purple Ubuntu Unity Plugin icon.  Then go down to the bottom right and click enable.  If it says it has to turn off other features or something to run this, just click accept or whatever it might be.  This *should* bring the unity bar back.